# jQuery - Return Values Matching a pattern to an Array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

My form has several `<p>` elements which are added dynamically.  This is how one would look:

```
<p id="numbox-1" class="numbox">1</p>
```

I need to set up a function so that when a button is clicked I get the id (the id's will be labeled numbox-1, numbox-2, etc) and the value of the p element for all of them on the page.

I need to pass the values to a php script that will process them, it would be nice if I could get the data as an array so I can use a for loop in php.

I have been using JSON to pass data, but Im not sure if that's the best way to go on this, please advise, thanks-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this, for example:

```
var arr = $('.numbox').map(function(){
            return { name: this.id, value: this.innerHTML };
          });
```

Then you could pass this as the `data` argument, for example:

```
$.post("mypage.php", arr);
```

This would result in a POST of the name/value pairs, like this:

```
numbox-1=1&numbox-2=XX....
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Quick follow up - is it possible to append another value pair the the arr - if so how?

Comment: @jriggs - you can add to `arr` before using it, for example `arr.push({ name: 'someName', value: 'someValue' });` *then* use it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'checking' buttons, but maybe this will help a bit.

```
$(function(){
  $("#send-button").click(function(){
    var data = [];
    $('.numbox').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      data.push( {
        id: $this.attr('id'),
        value: $this.html()
      } );
    });
    $.post('myurl.php', { numboxes: data });
  });
});
```

When `#send-button` is clicked, it creates a return array that contains objects for each numbox id and value.  It then posts that array to the server.

Comment: `.val()` is for input elements, this is a `<p>` and there's no need for `.attr("id")` you can simple to `this.id`.  Also, overall you can use `.map()` which is specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah the `val()` was a typo on my part.  While i agree that `this.id` is proper, I just gave the jQuery version as to not confuse people that don't know the raw JavaScript equivalents.  That said, I do agree that it's a good usage of `.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumbox()
{
    var objNumbox = new Array();
    $('.numbox').each(function(index){
        objNumbox[index] = $(this);
    });
    return objNumbox;
}

//Test it out
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = getNumbox();
    $(test).each(function(index){
        alert('ID: ' + $(test[index]).attr('id') + ' Text: ' + $(test[index]).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: On second though I'd use .map() as mentioned in the post above!